# How to use SQLAlchemy in MVC designed applications?

Tags: python, oop, model-view-controller, sqlalchemy

I know there is no absolute solution for my question. I just want to
hear your suggestions and how you do this in your practice.

In which layer of the MVC-pattern are all the SQLAlchemy objects
located?

How do you realize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlalchemy is related to the M in MVC. You define models for your objects and then sqlalchemy is an ORM that saves your models to a relational database.
SQLAlchemy objects are really just queries for interacting with your relational database but in a way that allows you to use models in your application.

Miguel Grinberg has an excellent tutorial on how to use Flask, a python microframework, that goes through all the concepts of MVC including sqlalchemy

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

There is a python sqlalchemy tutorial, as well as many others available on the sqlalchemy site at:
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/library.html#pythonsqlalchemytutorial

Comment: Flask is about web-development. This is quite far from my needs. And original MVC is far from web-development, too (of course we could discusse about that *fg*).

Comment: Yes flask is about web development but it will give you a good idea of sqlalchemy in relation to OOP and SQLAlchemy.